# The Eclipse "select workspace" dialog disappears when I switch to a different virtual desktop (VirtuaWin) - how to restore it?

Tags: eclipse, windows-xp, virtual-desktop

When eclipse starts up, it first show its splash screen and then pops up a dialog for selecting the desired workspace to open. If at this point I switch to a different virtual desktop and then come back later, only the splash screen is visible but the dialog is gone and I haven't found a way to get it back. I have to kill the eclipse process and start again.
Is there a way to recover from that problem whithout killing eclipse?

My setup:

Windows XP
VirtualWin 4.0.1
Eclipse Helios

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why it prompts you the first time Eclipse starts up but not after using a different virtual desktop. I assume you did not select "Use this as the default and do not ask again" on the "select workspace" dialog. If you don't mind waiting a bit, you can avoid killing Eclipse by loading the current workspace and then going to File > Switch Workspace.

Comment: That would of course be a workaround (just like waiting for eclipse to start up before switching to a different virtual desktop is). So this is not a serious problem I have but nevertheless I would like to know if there's a way to get hold of that lost window again.

Answer (score 0):

1. Start Eclipse.
2. Invoke Window menu on Workspace Launcher window. For example by clicking the middle mouse button on the window title bar, see Setup Dialog's Enable middle button window menu activation setting in VirtuaWin Help.
3. Click Add Window Rule.
4. Leave class name there e.g.: #32770.
5. Erase Window name and Process name.
6. Select Always manage windows of this type.
7. Click Add button.